# Unit-length vector x maximizing $||Mx+b||^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for the unit-length vector x which maximizes the expression
$||\mathbf{M}\,\mathbf{x}\,+\mathbf{b}||^2$ (euclidean norm), given a 2x2 (invertible) matrix M and a 2-vector b. For $||\mathbf{M}\,\mathbf{x}||^2$ I can simply use the eigen-decomposition of M -- is there an equivalent solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
{\cal F}\pars{{\bf x}^{\sf T}}
\equiv \pars{{\bf x}^{\sf T}M^{\sf T} + {\bf b}^{\sf T}}\pars{M{\bf x} + {\bf b}}
- \mu\pars{{\bf x}^{\sf T}{\bf x} - 1}
$$
$$
\delta{\cal F}\pars{{\bf x}^{\sf T}}
= \delta{\bf x}^{\sf T}\pars{M^{\sf T}M{\bf x} + M^{\sf T}{\bf b} - \mu{\bf x}}
$$
Solve $M^{\sf T}M{\bf x} + M^{\sf T}{\bf b} - \mu{\bf x}
=\pars{M^{\sf T}M - \mu}{\bf x} + M^{\sf T}{\bf b} = 0$. It yields:
${\bf x} = -\pars{M^{\sf T}M - \mu}^{-1}M^{\sf T}{\bf b}$. $\mu$ is determided by the condition:
$$
1 = {\bf x}^{\sf T}{\bf x} = {\bf b}^{\sf T}M\bracks{\pars{M^{\sf T}M - \mu}^{-1}}^{\sf T}\pars{M^{\sf T}M - \mu}^{-1}M^{\sf T}{\bf b}
$$

Comment: There should be an (irrelevant) factor $2$ in the differential.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Due to the presence of the Lagrange multiplier $\large\mu$, we can take $\large{\bf x}^{\sf T}$ and $\large{\bf x}$ as independendent variables. An additional variation respect $\large{\bf x}$ yields the transpose equation which is equivalent to the result we showed above. Thanks.

Comment: While frequently done in physics for complex valued fields, this is rather uncommon in variational calculus. That's why you see the factor $\frac12$ so often.

Comment: If the SVD $M=U\Sigma V^T$ is computed, the last equation can be simplified to $1=b^TUΣ(Σ^2-\mu I)^{-2}ΣU^Tb$, which "easily" leads to a polynomial equation of degree $2n$ for $\mu$.

Comment: Yeah, I also wound up with a forth-order polynomial in the end using a different derivation (expressing x in the eigenbasis of M). I was hoping there would be a simple analytic solution (without forth-order rootfinding). Oh Well :(